# Why is eclipse not allowing me to push code to github?

Tags: eclipse, github, push, egit

[image: Picture of push and save button not working]

For some reason when I'm pushing my code from github to eclipse the button just doesn't work, does anyone know why? P.S. The emails are valid, I just moved them to the side cause i dont want people knowing my email.

Comment: Did you actually *stage* any changes to commit?

Comment: Hey, sorry this is my first time doing it, I was just following some steps which never said to, so it's my fault. I thought selecting the ones in the unselected changes meant I was selecting what to push to github. Thank you so much for your response.